# From what distribution is QuTip's rand_herm sampled from?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, random-quantum-circuit, qutip

I am trying to figure out how QuTip samples Hamiltonians using its `rand_herm` function. It seems to use SciPy's `sparse.rand` function, but all I could find about this function is that it samples its values "uniformly". But I am not sure what SciPy means by "uniformly".

In short, I am trying to determine if `rand_herm` samples Hamiltonians uniformly.